# Is there a term to designate the property for an enzyme of catalyzing several reactions from the same substrate?

Tags: terminology, enzymes

LacZ (beta-galacosidase) catalyzes the hydrolysis of lactose into either galactose and glucose or allolactose.

Is there a term to designate such property for a single enzyme of catalysing several reactions from the same substrate (i.e. forming different alternative products)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the nomenclature of enzymes that catalyse more than one reaction because they fall into (at least) two structural types. One can refer to both of them as:

> multi-functional enzymes *or* multi-functional proteins

The latter term is used in a [1976 review of the topic](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.bi.45.070176.001043).

However for precision it is necessary to employ terminology that distinguishes between them, especially as the term *multi-functional* has also been used to indicate the different *physiological* functions that a single enzyme activity can have (e.g. in this review of [cysteine cathepsins](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrc1949)).

*The more common type* — to which the *lacZ* gene product does **not** belong — can be considered as *fusions of proteins containing separate catalytic activity*. Examples include the [AROM complex](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32632294/) of the shikimate pathway of fungi and protists, and the [fatty acid synthase complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_synthase) of eukaryotes. The Wikipedia entry for fatty acid synthase uses the term:

> multi-enzyme protein

The term, multi-enzyme *complex*, is often applied to such proteins (as above) but is also applied to complexes of individual enzymes, and so is *not* suitable as an unambigous descriptor for this type of enzyme.

*In the case of the product of the *lacZ* gene* there is a [single catalytic site, with a single binding site for the substrate](https://www.jbc.org/action/showPdf?pii=S0021-9258%2819%2933360-5) but an additional site to which the glucose produced by hydrolysis of the β-galactoside may or may not bind to produce allolactose. The authors of the linked paper describe this as:

> an enzyme with bifunctional activity

This is a description, rather than a ‘snappy’ term, and even so requires further elaboration to remove all ambiguity:

> an enzyme with a catalytic site possessing bifunctional activity

But this class of enzyme is relatively rare, which is why I suppose no ‘snappy’ term has (to my knowledge) arisen.